# How to typeset a table explaining Euclide's algorithm?

Tags: tables

I would like to typeset a table explaining Euclide's algorithm for calculating the greatest common divisor of two numbers, like this one:

[image]

How can I do that in LaTeX?

Comment: @Jake http://www.profezequias.net/algoritmo_de_euclides.gif

Comment: Are you looking for a way to *automatically* generate a table like the one you linked to? Or have you already calculated the numbers, and now you just want to typeset the table?

Comment: @Jake: Already figured, just want to know transcribe ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to use an `\array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{r|r|r|r|r}
   & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2\\\hline
24 & 15 & 9 & 6 & 3\\\hline
9 & 6 & 3 & 0
\end{array} = \text{mdc}(24,15)
\]
\end{document}
```